# What does `exec` with no arguments do?

Tags: shell, exec

`exec` with no arguments returns success and apparently does nothing. Why?

Comment: What would make you expect otherwise?

Comment: Why what? Why success? Why no apparent action? What do you expect? Did you bother to read the help text?

Comment: @RalfFriedl `man exec` returns `No manual entry for exec` and `exec --help` returns `zsh: exec requires a command to execute`. So no , unfortunately i couldn't read the help text.

Comment: `exec` is a shell builtin. You seem to use `zsh`, so see the `zsh` manual..

Comment: This is shell built-in, `man zshbuiltins`

Comment: Bash would have `help exec` to help with builtins, too bad Zsh doesn't have that. But in general, builtin commands don't have individual man pages, you have to look at the shell's manual. `type foo` would tell if something is a builtin, e.g. `type exec` says "exec is a shell builtin".

Comment: Oh i tried doing `whatis exec` i didn't know about `type`. I know i shouldn't use comments for this but i'm really grateful for the comments/answers in this site, they're so helpful to learn things, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way [Bash's manual puts it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec), the syntax of `exec` is

```
exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
```

and

> If *command* is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new process.

but,

> If no *command* is specified, redirections may be used to affect the current shell environment.

So, `exec` without anything else on the command line has no command to run, and no redirections to apply, hence nothing to do.

But e.g. `exec >> output.txt` also has no actual arguments to `exec`, however it does still apply the redirection to the shell.

That's similar in Zsh, and a POSIX feature, though the POSIX text is a bit harder to read.

Answer (score -2):

Placing these lines near the top of your shell will capture the output that is not further redirected in the script.

```
LOG=bash.out.txt
exec >"$LOG" 2>&1

echo "captured into $LOG"
echo "not captured into $LOG" > otherfile.txt
```

Comment: this answer would be more useful (IMO), if it explained the general concept applied here.

Comment: This is an interesting application of `exec` but seeing as the user says "apparently does nothing", and your code obviously does _something_, it would probably not be too far-fetched to assume that the user is trying to run `exec` without arguments and redirections. Your answer is not touching on this.